# Update domain url in laravel paginate api response

Tags: laravel, api

I am working in Microservices architecture.
I need your guidance in my implementation that I am working correctly or not.
I and internal service [Property] which calls from API Gateway.
In Property service I am sending responses using API resources with paginate, now the issue is my property service returns its internal URL within paginate. How can I change this custom domain URL from property to API gateway?
Or if I am doing something wrong please guide me about that. How can I use/implement paginate in internal services with next page click and search features?

[image]

I want to update the domain URL in the above image.

Thanks

Comment: It is on production server? If so look at your server documentation for proxypass. (ngnix/apache)

Answer (score 0):

Laravel has `withPath` [method for pagination](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/pagination#customizing-pagination-urls) since version 5.4.

You can set relative path or absolute url with this method.

I suggest you can send request with pagination base path and dynamically set inside microservice.